# How to distribute student data in an array of student table to different lecturers randomly

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm having issues with logic to distribute students in the `std_tbl` to different lecturers in `lec_tbl` randomly.and each lecturer has the capacity of students he cant have in the `lec_tbl`.

```
Std_MatricNo    Std_Name    Lecture
Std_001           Toure     Lec_1
Std_002           Neymar    Lec_2
Std_003           Messi     Lec_3
Std_004           Ronaldo   Lec_2
Std_005           Xavi      Lec_3
Std_006           Iniesta   Lec_2
Std_007           Falcao    Lec_2
```

This shows that `lec_1` has the capacity of 1 student and `lec_2` has the capacity of 4 students on till the last student in the table is assign to a lecturer.
  This is what I've done before getting stocked.

```
include 'connection.php';
$squery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students") or die(mysql_error());
$lquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lecturers") or die(mysql_error());
$scount = mysql_num_rows($squery);
if ($scount == 0)
{
    echo 'Sorry no registered students';
}
else
{
    $lcount = mysql_num_rows($lquery);
    if ($lcount == 0)
    {
        echo 'Sorry no Lecturer details';
    }
    else
    {
        while ($row_lec = mysql_fetch_array($lquery) and $row_std = mysql_fetch_array($squery))
        {

            $lec1 = $row_lec[0]['Capacity'];
            $lec_id = $row_lec['Lec_ID'];
            $std_id = $row_std['MatricNo'];
            $lec_surname = $row_lec['LSurname'];
            for ($j = 0; count($j < $lec1); $j++)
            {
                foreach($std_id as $k => $value)
                {
                    $existing = isset($lec_id[$i]);
                    if ($lec1 <= count($value))
                    {
                        $lec_id[$j][] = @$value;
                        unset($std_id[$k]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't even know if this is best way to do it. So I need somebody to help me

Comment: Hi Rasaq, You speak of the capacity of student per lecturer (if I got it right) but it don't seem to appear on the tabular data you've included. You only have a matric no., name, and lecture columns. I would assume it should have a capacity column, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes its captured into the variable $lec1